# How to play multiple wav files at the same time with no delay

Tags: c#, performance, wav, playback

I have a server that has some wav files, and when client connects he can ask the server to play each of them, when multiple clients connected, or when a client requests the same wav file twice before it completed once, I need to play it again, in parallel.

`SoundPlayer` doesn't allow that. I tried `WindowsMediaPlayer` object but when playing it in the following way:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
wmp.URL = sounds_folder;
```

It starts with a delay.

Does anyone knows a way to do this? Or maybe a way to load the buffers with the mediaplayer in the initialization so that that playing will be faster?

Comment: What if you create the WindowsMediaPlayer object already at initialisation time of your app?

Comment: If you're creating a `WindowsMediaPlayer` object wouldn't you need to create a new instance for each sound you want to play if the sounds are to play in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are using the wrong API. Media player is designed to render media files (consumer media) not short direct samples/clips

Google showed me

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229685.aspx
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030302.asp

the second even presumes you load the whole sample in-memory upfront so there is no need to worry about buffering times :)

Next: on parallel sounds; you should try the other API's. You might be in luck with them being async, otherwise use the thread pool by any of the methods

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
delegate.BeginInvoke(...)

of manually create a new Thread()... and Start() that. Beware of threading pitfalls (don't do any work and certainly don't share data without locking between threads) but for a simple 'fire and forget' background sound this is all going to be simple (provided that you keep the buffers with sound data around long enough - i.e. make them static)

Answer (score 0):

Try `wmp.controls.play();`.

That'll get rid of the lag, but unfortunately with WindowsMediaPlayer, you won't be able to play sounds more frequently than every approx 200ms without some of them being missed.